# Access 2007 combining and validating data from multiple sources

Tags: ms-access

I have data from two different sources that I need to combine. Some data is duplicated exactly and that's fine, easy to handle. Some data matches on two points and is different on a third, so in these cases I need to make a decision on which to keep and which to discard. Is there a query I can run to find any two rows that have the same identifier and the same date but a different description, then if one description is A whilst the other is B, to delete the row that has description B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I suggest you set up a form and subform. The form can be based on a query:

```
 SELECT FROM Table1
 INNER JOIN Table2
 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
 AND Table1.Date = Table2.Date
 WHERE Table1.=Description & "" <>  Table2.Description & ""
```

The addition of "" on both sides prevents mismatches being missed where one side is null.

The subform should be based on Table2 with the ID as the link child and master fields. You can then review both records before deciding on an action.

Comment: Thanks for that. Since sometimes I would need to delete a record from Table1 and sometimes Table2 I've set it up with two subforms, one for each table, with a Delete button beside each row. Now it's quick to compare and delete the description you don't need. However if I'm dealing with a few thousand records I'd like to automate the process where I can, and do a mass delete first where possible and then use the form to make decisions on the other cases. So if for ID1 and Date1, Table1 is 'This' and Table2 is 'That', keep rows with 'This' and delete rows with 'That'. Can that be done?

Comment: @Chelle As long as you are able to make a decision on exactly what needs to be kept/deleted in how ever many scenario's you may face, then yes this can also be done. However, if you are likely to face many different types of decisions then this will be a long process to fully integrate to a position where you feel you can trust it to take care of itself.

Comment: @Matt: There will be a number of set cases. This is dealing with surgical procedures, so there will be instances where one source codes it as A and another as B, but B will be better for our purposes. We'll also have cases where one source codes it a day later, so we end up with the same description from both sources but the date is a day out, and we'll go with the earlier of the two dates in these cases. How do you suggest proceeding?

Comment: @Chelle Always difficult without been able to see from that side, the only thing I can think of is using the "Case" statement within a VBA procedure to determine each condition, then under each of these introducing the relevant SQL code to execute in order to preserve/delete the desired rows from each table. "Word of warning" it will be a good idea to order the conditions by some form of priority if possible before beginning and then building up the code in a logical order. Apologies for not been able to give sample code etc but there isn't much I could give.

Comment: It seems that you have data supplied to you. If that is the case, you can easily add a YesNo column called Deleted to each table. Further, you can create a table of Decisions that are always to be deleted. You can then create a query that marks the relevant Deleted column for each table based on whether or not the decision is contained in the deleted table. This will allow you to quickly review columns marked deleted and ensure that relevant data is not lost.

Comment: @Chelle: I think what Matt is saying is that if you could write down a set of rules that governs the decision making, then you can automate it. Think of it as a decision tree. You may go through several criteria decisions as you branch out into the tree before finding the final outcome. I suggest you use a Multi-Level list in MS Word to build your decision tree.
You can use IIF within the SQL statements (could get real messy real quick if it's complex), or if you use VBA you'll have If-ElseIf-Else & Select-Case statements to help you out.

Comment: @Chelle: One other possible solution is to just append the 2 Description fields together. You may get duplicate data in the description, but you wont lose any data. This would be especially useful if the data you have is mostly for archival purposes.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Think I'm sorted, using a range of queries. Find duplications, update table from that list, delete the dups out of Table1 and Table2. Select against both tables for when Term1 is used in one and Term2 in the other, delete corresponding rows with the unwanted term. Then display the remainder side by side in 2 subforms with a delete button against each for the user to resolve which they want to use. Solves all problems I think and combines the automation I wanted with the user input.